# What does "debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed" mean?

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I have just installed Debian and I was just installing some packages using apt-get instal when I saw this message:

```
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
```

What does this mean? And once I have installed apt-utils how can configure the packages?

Comment: I have same question today

Answer (score 64, accepted):

apt-utils contains the `/usr/bin/apt-extracttemplates` program which is used when packages need to ask you questions about how to be configured.  This package being Priority: important, means it should really be installed except in rare circumstances.

If there is configuration pending, `dpkg-reconfigure [package]` will perform it. If you missed configuring a number of packages and don't know which, run `dpkg-reconfigure -au` to go through (a)ll (u)nseen configuration questions.

Comment: Is this utility required if I only need to install packages non-interactively? I ran into [an issue with it](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/issues/59).