# Avoid apt-utils warning in Debian Dockerfile

Tags: debian, docker, apt

When making Docker builds like this:

```
FROM debian:buster
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
      build-essential \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I get the following warning:

`debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed`

It appears to be harmless, but is there an easy way to avoid it?

This does not get rid of the warning:

```
FROM debian:buster
RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y --no-install-recommends \
      install build-essential
```

---

Here's a question about that warning in general: [What does "debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed" mean?](https://serverfault.com/questions/358943/what-does-debconf-delaying-package-configuration-since-apt-utils-is-not-insta?answertab=active)

Comment: You should execute `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` in one `RUN`.

Answer (score 3):

One way to deal with this is to tell `debconf` to not ask questions. You could do this for example via:

- `RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install ...`
- `RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && ...`
- `ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`

Please note: *Don't* use `ENV` to set this variable, as it would persist in the final image, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the clear suggestions. Unfortunately the message doesn't disappear (I edited the question to show the exact changes I made). I'm already using the `-y` flag to APT in an attempt to make it non-interactive; is `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` more than an alias for that?

Comment: @Lassi Using the `-y` switch for `APT` will make `APT` assume `yes` for questions. Setting the frontend interacts with `debconf`, the tool used to configure packages. Both switches aren't necessarily related. For an explanation of the various frontends available, see `man 7 debconf`, this manual is shipped via `debconf-doc`. Unfortunately, I can't tell why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr: For Docker, you can use something like:

`RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NOWARNINGS=yes apt-get -y ...`

---

Setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` does not quiet the debconf warning that "apt-utils is not installed", it just stops it from asking questions.

Setting `DEBCONF_NOWARNINGS=yes` causes debconf to

> DEBCONF_NOWARNINGS: Set to "yes" to disable some warnings that debconf may display. Does  not  suppress display of fatal errors.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to ignore this warning. It appears because the package you are installing can be configured interactively during installation. This warning means that the interactive configuration has been skipped. The default configuration is used instead, and using the default configuration is usually not an issue.

In order not to have this warning, you have to install `apt-utils` and disable the interactive configuration using the environment variable `DEBIAN_FRONTEND`. You will still get the warning while installing `apt-utils`, but after that, the new installation will be free of those warnings.

This can be done by adding the following lines to your Dockerfile:

```
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils
```